# Values are not updating

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, webforms

```
protected void gvExample_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   string s = gvExample.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();           
   TextBox FirstName = gvExample.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;
   TextBox LastName = gvExample.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox;
   TextBox Title = gvExample.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTitle") as TextBox;
   TextBox Country = gvExample.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCountry") as TextBox;
   string query ="UPDATE USER_DETAILS SET LAST_NAME='" + LastName.Text + "',FIRST_NAME='" + FirstName.Text + "',TITle='" + Title.Text + "',COUNTRY='" + Country.Text + "'";

   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection"].ConnectionString);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
   gvDatabind();
}
```

The values are not updating. They are updating as lastname.Text firstname.Text.
Please help me.

Comment: You have no where clause on the update, so every row will change, and you are extremely vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Please look into parameterized SQL queries, and think about making this a stored procedure.

Comment: You probably need a where clause in there - at the moment it will update the whole table. Also, parameterization is a always good idea.

Comment: And you should wrap the connection and command in `using` blocks to make sure they're disposed of properly.

Comment: @user3433135 Please expand on "The values are not updating. They are updating as lastname.Text firstname.Text." if you really want someone to help you out

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your variables `FirstName` etc are not being cast as `TextBox` properly... What if you try something like the following cast

```
GridViewRow row = gvExample.Rows[e.RowIndex];
var Id = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text;
var FirstName = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
var LastName = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;

string query ="UPDATE USER_DETAILS SET LAST_NAME='" + LastName + "',FIRST_NAME='" + FirstName "'"; // and your other values...
```

Obviously also including a WHERE clause and `int.parse` the Id value for that and generally making the example code you've shown more production ready.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'. getting error

Comment: I think that shows part of the issue... you've got `Literals` not `TextBoxes`